# Intermittent Authentication Errors with BotFramework on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I'm using the botframework on Azure. I get intermittent authentication errors when starting to interact with the bot. If you just ignore the error, the bot continues to function normally, and you don't get the error all the time.

This is the innermost error: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized' The error happens in the MessagesController+d__3.MoveNext method.

I tried debugging as shown in the "Troubleshooting Bot Framework" document and everything checks out fine.

Error Details:

[{"parsedStack":[{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Connector, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotState+d__8.MoveNext","level":0,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":1,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":2,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Connector, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotStateExtensions+d__7.MoveNext","level":3,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":4,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":5,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ConnectorStore+-LoadAsync>d__2.MoveNext","level":6,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":7,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":8,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore+d__8.MoveNext","level":9,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":10,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":11,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore+-LoadAsync>d__6.MoveNext","level":12,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":13,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":14,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.BotDataBase`1+<LoadData>d__16.MoveNext","level":15,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":16,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":17,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.BotDataBase`1+d__8.MoveNext","level":18,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":19,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":20,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTaskManagerBotDataLoader+d__11.MoveNext","level":21,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":22,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":23,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask+d__3.MoveNext","level":24,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":25,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":26,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask+d__2.MoveNext","level":27,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":28,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":29,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation+d__4.MoveNext","level":30,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":31,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":32,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser+d__5.MoveNext","level":33,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser+d__5.MoveNext","level":34,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":35,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":36,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogPostToBot+d__3.MoveNext","level":37,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":38,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":39,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation+d__11.MoveNext","level":40,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":41,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":42,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac, Version=3.16.1.38846, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation+d__6.MoveNext","level":43,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":44,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":45,"line":0},{"assembly":"Bot Application1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","method":"RiBot.MessagesController+d__3.MoveNext","level":46,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":47,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":48,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions+d__3`1.MoveNext","level":49,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":50,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":51,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker+d__0.MoveNext","level":52,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":53,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":54,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute+d__5.MoveNext","level":55,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute+d__5.MoveNext","level":56,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":57,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":58,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute+d__0.MoveNext","level":59,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":60,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":61,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult+d__2.MoveNext","level":62,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":63,"line":0},{"assembly":"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":64,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher+d__1.MoveNext","level":65,"line":0}],"outerId":"0","message":"Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'","type":"Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorResponseException","id":"59886687"}]

Comment: What does the bot do? Does it access a protected resource? Does it have permissions to that resource? etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the version you are using 3.16.1.38846 where if you do not talk to the bot for about an hour the token will expire and not be refreshed until the second message is sent.  Try upgrading to the [newest version 3.17.0.42969](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/3.17.0.42969) (of v3)it should resolve this issue for you

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've installed the new version. I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: Will you file an issue in the [botbuilder-v3](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-V3) repo so we can track it better

Comment: Done. I've added it.